# How to find out if the return Url is being passed back via form post when signing in using IE developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer, url, authentication, return, form-submit

I am working on a website with a couple of secure pages. 
When I click on any of the links to access these pages IM automatically redirected to the sign -in page, which is normal behavior.

However, on signing in, instead of being directed to the original page I requested or clicked on I am brought back to the home page.

I would like to find out if the return Url is being passed back via form post when signing in.

How do I find this using IE developer tools or firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember you cannot log requests/responses in IE developer toolbar. But there are powerful tools like [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (haven't tried this one myself) for this purpose.

In Firebug you can switch to the *Net* tab and access data transfer related information. If you expand a POST request, you will find a tab that shows the data that were posted with the request. In Google Chrome you will get the same functionality with the built in developer tools on the *Network* tab.

If you are debugging encrypted (https) pages it's the easiest to use Firebug because Fiddler and Wireshark must be specially configured to allow this.

Comment: Thanks. My "retrun url =" field has no value to it. What does this mean?

Comment: It seems that there was no value for this field sent to the server. For determining a reason it would be necessary that you give us more information on the server side technology/framework etc. you are using.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 and later show the request and response in the Network tab of the F12 Developer tools. Decrypting secure traffic in Fiddler requires you click 4 times. It's easy.